# KeyError: 'children' webscraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from [this website](https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/grotte-comune-ag/spese/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo) but the code keeps returning the KeyError: 'children' error. The code I have right now is:

```
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os

r = requests.get('https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/grotte-comune-ag/spese/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo')
p = re.compile("var bilancio_tree = (.*?);")
data = p.search(r.text).group(1)

data = json.loads(data)

all_data = []
        
for d in data:
    for v in d["values"]:
        for kk, vv in v.items():
            all_data.append([d["label"], "-", kk, vv.get("abs"), vv.get("pc")])
            
    for c in d["children"]:
        for v in c["values"]:
            for kk, vv in v.items():
                all_data.append(
                    [d["label"], c["label"], kk, vv.get("abs"), vv.get("pc")]
                    )
                        
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["label 1", "label 2", "year", "abs", "PC"])
```

I am not sure why it's happening. **print(data)** returns the following:

```
[{'slug': 'pcox-quadro-4-26', 'label': 'TOTALE GENERALE DELLE SPESE', 'values': [{'2021': {'abs': 20284661.0, 'pc': 3790.10855754858}}, {'2022': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}, {'2023': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}], 'composition': {'hash': '5f19812c', 'correnti_value': 6362017.319999999, 'correnti_perc': 31.36368569334237, 'investimenti_value': 5301441.209999999, 'investimenti_perc': 26.135222126709433, 'incremento_fin_value': 0.0, 'incremento_fin_perc': 0.0, 'altro_value': 8619152.469999999, 'altro_perc': 42.49098602140799, 'label': 'Spese per conto terzi e partite di giro'}}, {'slug': 'pcox-quadro-4-1', 'label': 'Disavanzo di Amministrazione', 'values': [{'2021': {'abs': 210404.27, 'pc': 39.3132044095665}}, {'2022': {'abs': 210404.27, 'pc': 39.3132044095665}}, {'2023': {'abs': 210404.27, 'pc': 39.3132044095665}}], 'children': [], 'composition': {'hash': 'bf7de1c6'}}, {'slug': 'pcox-quadro-4-2', 'label': 'Servizi istituzionali, generali e di gestione', 'values': [{'2021': {'abs': 5291002.99, 'pc': 988.602950298954}}, {'2022': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}, {'2023': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}], 'children': [{'slug': 'pcox-quadro-4-2-1', 'label': 'Organi istituzionali', 'values': [{'2021': {'abs': 279001.21, 'pc': 52.1302709267564}}, {'2022': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}, {'2023': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}], 'children': [{'slug': 'pcox-quadro-4-2-1-23', 'label': 'Titolo 1 - Spese correnti', 'values': [{'2021': {'abs': 279001.21, 'pc': 52.1302709267564}}, {'2022': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}, {'2023': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}]}, {'slug': 'pcox-quadro-4-2-1-33', 'label': 'Titolo 2 - Spese in conto capitale', 'values': [{'2021': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}, {'2022': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}, ............]
```

Comment: `d` doesn't contain the key `'children'`. Specifically, the 0th element of `data` doesn't contain the key.

Comment: As @MichaelRuth says, one of the elements doesn't have that key. You could either check if it exists (e.g., `if "children" in d.keys()`) first or wrap that iteration in a `try/except KeyError` block

Comment: Thanks, but the code works well with this data:
`[{'slug': 'pcox-quadro-2-11', 'label': 'Totale generale delle Entrate', 'values': [{'2021': {'abs': 58451236.4, 'pc': 7596.98939433325}}, {'2022': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}, {'2023': {'abs': 0.0, 'pc': 0.0}}], 'children': []}, {'slug': 'pcox-quadro-2-2', 'label': 'Entrate correnti di natura tributaria, contributiva e perequativa', 'values': [{'2021': {'abs': 13204387.28,...]` from https://openbilanci.it/armonizzati/bilanci/racalmuto-comune-ag/entrate/dettaglio?year=2021&type=preventivo

Comment: My understanding is that both the webpages have an identical structure, then not sure why it's not working. Sorry if it doesn't make sense